# How to get the image src as a variable and display an image from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently creating an image gallery to work on my skills.

I have an array that consists of images that I have from a folder called 'images'.

I have an image that has an id of 'imgsrc' with an empty source on my HTML page, so it's not displaying anything. I would like to be able to have access to the first image in my 'images' folder and display it as the source for my image using Javascript.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
var images = ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg', 'images/4.jpg', 'images/5.jpg', 'images/6.jpg','images/7.jpg', 'images/8.jpg', 'images/9.jpg'];

var imgsrc = document.getElementById('imgsrc').src;

var index = 0;

imgsrc = images[index];
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<section class="gallery">

  <img id='imgsrc' src="">

</section>
```

What should I do ?

I appreciate all responses

Comment: You have to specifically set the src on the element itself. Changing the variable value will have no effect on the element that you got the initial value from

Comment: **document.getElementById("imgsrc").src  = images[index];**  is enough

Comment: @RohitasBehera no need to put your answer in a comment also. OP gets notified when answers are added. Comments like *"check my answer"* are just needless noise

Comment: okay ..removing answers then

Comment: Keep in mind that the way you actually have this reference stored and the reference relative to that folder.  You MIGHT store it in the root images specifically i.e. `"/images/myimage.jpg"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `imgsrc` stores the string value and not a reference to the image src. Edit it directly:

```js
var images = ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg', 'images/4.jpg', 'images/5.jpg', 'images/6.jpg','images/7.jpg', 'images/8.jpg', 'images/9.jpg'];

var index = 0;
console.log(document.getElementById('imgsrc').src);
document.getElementById('imgsrc').src = images[index];
console.log(document.getElementById('imgsrc').src);
```

```html
<section class="gallery">

  <img id='imgsrc' src="">

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg', 'images/4.jpg', 'images/5.jpg', 'images/6.jpg','images/7.jpg', 'images/8.jpg', 'images/9.jpg'];

var imgsrc = document.getElementById('imgsrc');

var index = 0;

imgsrc.setAttribute('src',images[index]);
```

Try to use `setAttribute()`.

Comment: That's what I just did, but all I get in the console is 'imgsrc.setAttribute is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

Works with **Minimum Code !!!**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>

<section class="gallery">

  <img alt="sd" id='imgsrc' src="">

</section>

 

<script>
 
var images = ['http://i65.tinypic.com/zl2rfr.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg', 'images/4.jpg', 'images/5.jpg', 'images/6.jpg','images/7.jpg', 'images/8.jpg', 'images/9.jpg']; 

var index = 0;

document.getElementById("imgsrc").src  = images[index];
 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Get the element then set its src

```
var images = ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg', 'images/3.jpg', 'images/4.jpg', 'images/5.jpg', 'images/6.jpg','images/7.jpg', 'images/8.jpg', 'images/9.jpg'];
var imgsrc = document.getElementById('imgsrc');// get element
var index = 0;
imgsrc.src = images[index];
console.log(imgsrc.src);
```